# git mergetool with opendiff always moves me to "no branch"

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm trying to bring a feature branch ("tricoherence") up-to-date with the master branch using this command:

```
git rebase master tricoherence
```

Unsurprisingly, I have a merge conflict. No problem, I fire up `git mergetool` and save the day. Of critical importance (I think) is that I'm using `opendiff` (== FileMerge) to resolve merges. When I save the file in FileMerge, I go back to the terminal, and find that I'm no longer in my branch:

```
computer$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
  tricoherence
```

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I got the answer on the #git irc channel:

> **doener** : rebase always operates on a detached HEAD. The original branch head is updated once the rebase is complete
>
> **SethRobertson** : `git rebase --continue` I believe.  I believe you need to `git add` the files first

So, in order:

```
git rebase master tricoherence
git mergetool
# remember to delete the <file>.orig file made by opendiff
git add <file>
git rebase --continue
```